# Rename R\ Directory in devtools package

Tags: r, roxygen2, r-devtools

I'm working on a data analysis project that will use code in languages other than R alongside it. Is there a way to have devtools find renamed directories (e.g moving the R\ directory into "code\R" or man\ into "docs/R")?

Thank you!